# Function Return Array PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to create a function that gets the name and clientid. What is the proper way to return an array? so that I can have multiple values returned.

```
function get_client_name($conn, $clientid){
  $response = array();
  $query = "SELECT NAME, CLIENTID FROM LCCLIENT WHERE CLIENTID = '". $clientid ."'";
  $sql = oci_parse($conn, $query);
  $exec = oci_execute($sql);

  if($exec){
      $row = oci_fetch_array($sql);
      $response[] = array(
          'CLIENTID' => trim($row['CLIENTID']),
          'NAME' => trim($row['NAME'])
      );
  }

  return json_encode($response);
}

echo get_client_name($conn, '2000000800')[0]['CLIENTID'];
echo get_client_name($conn, '2000000800')[0]['NAME'];
```

Comment: Just `return $response`

Comment: You don't need to select `CLIENTID`, you already know it. You also may be open to SQL injections. Best to parameterize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just return your array, without encoding it in JSON format. Also don't call this function two times, because it's redundant to call DB two times for the same data. Second thing, you shouldn't pass `$conn` in this function. You should develop some structure for database connections.

```
function get_client_name($conn, $clientid)
{
    $response = array();
    $query = "SELECT NAME, CLIENTID FROM LCCLIENT WHERE CLIENTID = '" . $clientid . "'";
    $sql = oci_parse($conn, $query);
    $exec = oci_execute($sql);

    if ($exec) {
        $row = oci_fetch_array($sql);
        $response[] = array(
            'CLIENTID' => trim($row['CLIENTID']),
            'NAME' => trim($row['NAME'])
        );
    }

    return $response;
}

$clientName = get_client_name($conn, '2000000800');

echo $clientName[0]['CLIENTID'];
echo $clientName[0]['NAME'];
```

Comment: Do I need to include my connection inside my function?

Comment: If you don't use any framework that's ok, but you will regret if system gets bigger, because it's hard to maintain this kind of functions. You should write code more object-oriented, but this is not main purpose of this question. You can read more about the concept, i.e.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474876/connect-to-mysql-database-using-php-oop-concept

Comment: Thank you I will consider that in the future